# What is `recommit` for miner when PoW was working?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I see a config named `recommit` in go-ethereum source code, the miner module, what's it for?

When some node is mining, maybe 10s-15s a new block may be sealed, the default recommit internal is 3s, it can interrupt the sealing process then other miners can seal a new block early than me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in the Ethereum Mainnet, the average mining time is around 15 seconds. But during this "LONG"' procedure, lots of new transactions with higher gas price will arrive but they have to wait a few seconds to be included even the price is higher than the txs in the mining block.

So we have this idea to re-create the mining block with configured interval(`--miner.recommit`).
In this way, we can always try to fill the mining block with the highest price txs.

The benefits of this includes the mining pool can get a higher revenue, it's fairer for users who send the high price transaction, and it's basically no overhead for switching the mining block in the miner side.

The default interval for `recommit` is 3 seconds. You can choose the value by yourself (min is 1 second and max is 15 seconds).

See: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21359

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/1913b50111bd30dda5b43171c1f880f0127d40e1/miner/worker.go#L488 it only works when consensus engine is clique? does not work for mainnet pow and modern pos?

Comment: It works for when the consensus engine is clique and mainnet, but I don't think it works for modern pos because there are no miners anymore.